# How to remove carriage return & space and store strings in the array properly?

Tags: java, arrays, carriage-return

I have a text file with 4 lines of data.

```
AAA,ZZZ,555,10
BBB,KKK,908977,5
CCCCC,WIKY PODAR,130000,15
DDDDD,XXXXX555,130110,30
```

then I read them and split them , remove the carrige return , replaced antoher coma and stored them into an Array.

Print out the arry , It looks fine :

```
[AAA, ZZZ, 555, 10, BBB, KKK, 908977, 5, CCCCC, WIKY PODAR, 130000, 15, DDDDD, XXXXX555, 130110, 30]
```

**However, I printed out them indivisually, 10 and BBB became a single array element. How to sperate them into two different array elements?**

Thank you.

output:

```
AAA
ZZZ
555
10, BBB
KKK
908977
5, CCCCC
WIKY PODAR
130000
15, DDDDD
XXXXX555
130110
30
```

---

```
while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                String testString2 = new String(buffer);
                String delim2 = ",";
                String[] token2 = testString2.split(delim2);
                String[] myStringArray = new String[token2.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < token2.length; i++) {
                    token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("[\n]", "");
                    token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("[\r]", ", ");
                    myStringArray[i] = token2[i];
                }
```

Comment: There is a `\n` between `10` and `BBB`, no comma. So because you split at the commas, it considers `10` and `BBB` to be part of a single group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try the following way instead? Shorter and sweeter?

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
for(String line : lines) {
    String[] words = line.split(",");
    System.arrayCopy(words, 0, myStringArray, myStringArray.length, words.length);
}
```

However if you really want to do it the way you have, you need to

replace

`token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("[\r]", ", ");`

with

`token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("[\r]", "");`

There is no need to replace the carriage return with a comma.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering the question. I tried not to replace carriage return with comma, then i print out the Array. The Array now has carriage returns.

Comment: You need to replace the carriage returns with an empty space the way I have shown in my answer.

Comment: yes i did replace the carriage retuens with an empty space. But if you print out the array as a whole, you will notice that , the array has carriage return now.

Comment: Can you try `token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");`

Comment: hi, i tried with this code. the array displayed properbaly , but when i check the length of the array. it outputs 13. which means that 10 and BBB are still a single array element , not seperated .

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to replace the carriage return with `replaceAll()`. The carriage return acts as a delimiter, just like a comma, in your data.

Here is code that reads each line, splits on commas, and aggregates the tokens.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ParseTextFile {

    public static String[] read(String fileName) throws IOException {

        // Will hold all tokens from the file.
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Open the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String buffer = null;

        // Read the file line-by-line.
        while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null)   {

            // Split this line on commas and add each token to the list.
            String[] tokens = buffer.split(",");

            for (String token : tokens) {
                list.add(token);
            }
        }

        br.close();

        String[] array = new String[list.size()];
        return list.toArray(array);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        String[] result = read("text.txt");
        for (String string : result) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", string);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
AAA
ZZZ
555
10
BBB
KKK
908977
5
CCCCC
WIKY PODAR
130000
15
DDDDD
XXXXX555
130110
30
```